# SSL handshake faliure in java application

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

we have an application that connects to an application hosted in 3rd party system, while calling it we are getting  SSL handshake failure error from the application deployed in  linux tomcat8.X using java1.8

I add the root and intermediate certificate in java's cacerts files  still face handshake error

the 3rd party root and intermediate certificate is based on Zscaler

I used a standalone application to debug  (to know the certificate used by the application)  that also fails.
So what certificate I am missing? Also, how will I know what certificate am I miss to establish the connection?

**Standalone application Below**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException;

public class ConnectClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConnectClient().testIt();

    }

    private void testIt() {

        String https_url = "https://<3rdpartyhostpage>.html";

        URL url;

        try {

            url = new URL(https_url);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            print_https_cert(con);
            print_content(con);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void print_https_cert(HttpsURLConnection con) {

        if (con != null) {

            try {

                System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());
                System.out.println("Cipher Suite : " + con.getCipherSuite());
                // con.getCer
                System.out.println("\n");

                Certificate[] certs = con.getServerCertificates();
                for (Certificate cert : certs) {
                    System.out.println("Cert Type : " + cert.getType());
                    System.out.println("Cert Hash Code : " + cert.hashCode());
                    System.out.println("Cert Public Key Algorithm : " + cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
                    System.out.println("Cert Public Key Format : " + cert.getPublicKey().getFormat());
                    System.out.println("Cert Public Key String : " + cert.getPublicKey().toString());

                    // cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm()

                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
                }

            } catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    private void print_content(HttpsURLConnection con) {
        if (con != null) {

            try {

                System.out.println("****** Content of the URL ********");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String input;

                while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(input);
                }
                br.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

**The error getting is**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at ConnectClient.print_https_cert(ConnectClient.java:45)
        at ConnectClient.testIt(ConnectClient.java:28)
        at ConnectClient.main(ConnectClient.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
        ... 12 more
```

**The Root and Intermdiate used by 3rd application is Digicertificate **
[image]

When the SSL debug is enabled the following is the output

```
System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Inaccessible trust store: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts
trustStore is: /etc/pki/java/cacerts
trustStore type is: jks
trustStore provider is: 
the last modified time is: Thu Apr 08 02:25:50 UTC 2021
Reload the trust store
Reload trust certs
Reloaded 146 trust certs

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x83be056904246b1a1756ac95991c74a
  Valid from Fri Nov 10 00:00:00 UTC 2006 until Mon Nov 10 00:00:00 UTC 2031


adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Trusted Root G4, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Trusted Root G4, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x59b1b579e8e2132e23907bda777755c
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 12:00:00 UTC 2013 until Fri Jan 15 12:00:00 UTC 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1fda3eb6eca75c888438b724bcfbc91
  Valid from Fri Mar 08 12:00:00 UTC 2013 until Wed Mar 08 12:00:00 UTC 2023


adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x2ac5c266a0b409b8f0b79f2ae462577
  Valid from Fri Nov 10 00:00:00 UTC 2006 until Mon Nov 10 00:00:00 UTC 2031


adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Tue Jun 29 17:39:16 UTC 2004 until Thu Jun 29 17:39:16 UTC 2034

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xce7e0e517d846fe8fe560fc1bf03039
  Valid from Fri Nov 10 00:00:00 UTC 2006 until Mon Nov 10 00:00:00 UTC 2031


adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4e1e7a4dc5cf2f36dc02b42b85d159f
  Valid from Tue Oct 22 12:00:00 UTC 2013 until Sun Oct 22 12:00:00 UTC 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root G3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root G3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0x55556bcf25ea43535c3a40fd5ab4572
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 12:00:00 UTC 2013 until Fri Jan 15 12:00:00 UTC 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xa3508d55c292b017df8ad65c00ff7e4
  Valid from Thu Sep 24 00:00:00 UTC 2020 until Mon Sep 23 23:59:59 UTC 2030

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xb931c3ad63967ea6723bfc3af9af44b
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 12:00:00 UTC 2013 until Fri Jan 15 12:00:00 UTC 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root G3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root G3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0xba15afa1ddfa0b54944afcd24a06cec
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 12:00:00 UTC 2013 until Fri Jan 15 12:00:00 UTC 2038
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=SZAFIR ROOT CA2, O=Krajowa Izba Rozliczeniowa S.A., C=PL
  Issuer:  CN=SZAFIR ROOT CA2, O=Krajowa Izba Rozliczeniowa S.A., C=PL
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x3e8a5d07ec55d232d5b7e3b65f01eb2ddce4d6e4
  Valid from Mon Oct 19 07:43:30 UTC 2015 until Fri Oct 19 07:43:30 UTC 2035

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x33af1e6a711a9a0bb2864b11d09fae5
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 12:00:00 UTC 2013 until Fri Jan 15 12:00:00 UTC 2038

keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
main, the previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=appsvcext.microfocus.com) was replaced with (type=host_name (0), value=appsvcext.microfocus.com)
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1617813016 bytes = { 135, 101, 76, 119, 48, 190, 41, 85, 66, 16, 132, 66, 244, 108, 164, 186, 210, 121, 207, 77, 213, 210, 56, 244, 237, 225, 160, 47 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=appsvcext.microfocus.com]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 218
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
****** Content of the URL ********
```

Comment: Please run your standalone application with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` and post the resulting output in your question. It is long.

Comment: added the SSL debug ( trimming done to accommodate output.

Comment: Well it's not about the certificates, right? You didn't even get a `ServerHello` let alone a certificate. Must be a cipher suite or ignature algorithm or or TLS version problem.

Comment: So cipher in the client ( source from call is made) or in the destination need to update?